# c/c++ : header file not found

Tags: c++, c, include

Some header files are present in `/src/dir1/` (eg: `a.h`, `b.h`, `c.h` etc). My source file is present in `/src/dir2/file.cpp`. I used some header files that are present in `/src/dir1/` but during compilation I got errors like `header file not found`.

Then I changed the include path like `#include "../src/dir1/a.h"`, then error is gone in `file.cpp` but I get `not found` error in the headers files that are present in `/src/dir1`. Because I included the header file say `a.h`, that `a.h` included some other header files that are present in `/src/dir1/` (say `b.h` and `c.h` present in `a.h`).

How to add the header file (`a.h`) in `/src/dir2/file.cpp` so that it should not ask to modify the include path in the header files that are present in `/src/dir1/`?

Note: I am using `scons` to build.

Comment: You would need either `"include "../dir1/a.h"` or `#include "../..src/dir1/a.h"` to find the file.  But embedding `..` in include paths is a bad idea (as is using an absolute pathname).  Use either `#include "a.h"` or `#include "dir1/a.h"` and an appropriate `-I` command line option when compiling.

Answer (score 10):

You can add directories to the include file search path using the `-I` command line parameter of `gcc`:

```
gcc -I/src/dir1 file.cpp
```

Comment: The `-I` option is required by POSIX; `gcc` implements it.  I don't know of a compiler where it is not supported — AFAIK, even MSVC supports `-I` (maybe as `/I`).

Answer (score 2):

[SCons FAQ](http://www.scons.org/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#How_do_I_get_SCons_to_find_my_.23include_files.3F):

How do I get SCons to find my #include files?

If your program has #include files in various directories, SCons must somehow be told in which directories it should look for the #include files. You do this by setting the CPPPATH variable to the list of directories that contain .h files that you want to search for:

```
env = Environment(CPPPATH='inc')
env.Program('foo', 'foo.c')
```

SCons will add to the compilation command line(s) the right -I options, or whatever similar options are appropriate for the C or C++ compiler you're using. This makes your SCons-based build configuration portable.

Note specifically that you should not set the include directories directly in the CCFLAGS variable, as you might initially expect:

```
env = Environment(CCFLAGS='-Iinc')    # THIS IS INCORRECT!
env.Program('foo', 'foo.c')
```

This will make the program compile correctly, but SCons will not find the dependencies in the "inc" subdirectory and the program will not be rebuilt if any of those #include files change.

Answer (score 2):

It's not found because it's not there.  You have one extra level of indirection.  A file in "/src/foo/" would include a file in "/src/bar/" with "include ../bar/the_file"

In other words, in your example, there is no "../src/" relative to dir1 or dir2.  The relationship is "dir1/../dir2" or "dir1/../../src/dir2"

To see this for yourself, make dir1 your current directory (chdir /src/dir1) and compare the difference betwee "ls .." and "ls ../src".  The second ls will not work but the first one will.

Make sense?  hope that helps