# Includes work in .c file, but not in .h file

Tags: c

I'm able to compile the following with no warnings using `gcc -c program.c -o program.o`

In `program.h`

```
#include<math.h>
```

In `program.c`

```
#include<sys/types.h>
#include"program.h"
```

But not this:

In `program.h`

```
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<math.h>
```

In `program.c`

```
#include"program.h"
```

If done the latter way, I get implicit declarations of all functions called from any libraries included after `sys/types.h`. For example:

```
program.c:352:55: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘pow’
program.c:352:55: note: include ‘<math.h>’ or provide a declaration of ‘pow’
```

Why is this?

Comment: Well, what warnings do you get?

Comment: Edited to include the issue I get.

Comment: Don't describe the error messages, *show* them.  Copy/paste **exactly** what the compiler outputs.  Also, show enough code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: it's an almost [universal convention](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/issues/769) that includes are written with a space, for example `#include <math.h>`, rather than `#include<math.h>`.

Comment: Smells like something in the environment is broken. Please share your environment, what you are compiling and what flags you are passing.

Comment: Is this really all the code you have in `program.h` and `.c`?

Comment: have you tried `#pragma once` on the top of both files?

Comment: "get implicit declarations of all functions called from any libraries included after sys/types.h" --> But there are no function calls posted, no line 352.  A [mcve] would be more  useful rather than only a description of code.

Comment: @GHOSTHUNT system headers can be included multiple times. That can't be the problem.

Comment: @Acorn Added compiler command.

Comment: @meaning-matters I'll get you a more code. This is part of a behemoth of a code base.

Comment: Something else must be wrong somewhere in the few hundred lines you're having. Please delete all code from these files until the issue disappears and you should be close to solving this yourself.

Comment: @meaning-matters got a minimum reproducible example. Standby.

Comment: You need to add `-lm` flag. `gcc -c program.c -o program.o -lm`.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19372317/c-failing-to-compile-cant-find-math-h-functions

Comment: @KrishnaKanthYenumula I had seen that before posting. Not the answer.

Comment: Guess: In editing `program.h` back and forth, file not saved as expected prior to compilation.

Comment: @Evan Did you add `-lm` tag??

Comment: @KrishnaKanthYenumula yes

Comment: @KrishnaKanthYenumula The error is a compilation error.  `-lm` solves a link time error.

Comment: @KrishnaKanthYenumula: Adding `-lm` solves a linkng issue. The error messages above occur during compilation.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I'm baffled at this point. I got to a minimum reproducible result, and it compiled...

Comment: EvanHendler See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65267805/include-sys-types-h-in-header-file#comment115387573_65267805).

Comment: Are you kidding me... it was because of `program.h.gch`

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17475268/c-c-header-file-not-found/17475422

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the error was caused by a file `program.h.gch` within the compilation directory. These are precompiled headers. `gcc` looks for these prior to actually compiling. The compiler was using a precompiled header without `#include sys/types.h`, vice `program.h` which had the correct `includes`.

See [What is a .h.gch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241399/what-is-a-h-gch-file) for more information.