# I have downloaded nlohmann with home-brew, but I can't include it in my cpp projects

Tags: c++, makefile, homebrew, nlohmann-json

I have downloaded nlohmann with home-brew, but when I went to #include it the library never showed up and I got the error file not found, so I checked home-brew and the file was downloaded I just can't find out what is wrong.

Comment: If you want to make your post into a more answerable question, you should probably aim for this format: when I compile this small piece of code (included) with this command (gcc and/or clang command line with all arguments) it tells me (verbatim quote of error message), (optional:) I think it cannot find the file (file) which in my install is at (directory).

Comment: Most likely you're missing some `-I` compiler arguments, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17475268/c-c-header-file-not-found

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.